# Overstayed in India and subsequently refused: Want to know what to do now?

Tags: visas, india, visa-refusals

When the last time my girlfriend came to india on tourist visa she overstayed for 4days and now its been 3years and the indian embassy in minsk, belarus(Europe) is not giving her visa. They are not giving any reason for that just saying u can ask from FRRO office in india .. but when i gone to FRRO office (Delhi) they are not telling me anything . I dont know what to do and how to know that is she blacklisted or not. And if she is blacklisted than what to do in this situation , so that she can come to india .

Comment: What to do: you instruct a qualified solicitor with a practice area in visas for India. The BCI can help you avoid being scammed, check http://www.barcouncilofindia.org/  Having said that, your question is vague to the extent that we may not be able to help you further. Close voting as 'unclear', use the BCI.